# Insert query for excel upload in php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Here is my code for extracting data present in an excel sheet,i have extract the data but unable to insert it to my database

```
if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        //$sql_data = "SELECT * FROM prod_list_1 ";
        while (($Data = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            echo $Data[0];
            $sql = "INSERT into tbl_userdata ('name','svp_name','mobileno','email') values ('$Data[0]')";

        }
        fclose($file);
```

But query not working.
Here is the output of `$Data[0]`[image]

Comment: Your code has syntax errors and you use $Data[0] for the echo, but $emapData[0] for the insert.

Comment: You never close your SQL? its missing a " at the end?

Comment: Its  mistake that occured during asking the question.

Comment: I think the output you posted is not the output of $Data[0], but the complete array $Data, right? $Data[0] is the name, $Data[1] is the svp_name, ...?

Comment: Yes you are correct,but how can i extract each data

Answer (score 0):

you have to execute you sql also:but skip the headers.

try: `$mysqli->query($sql);` or the one which you are using like mysql.

note:this code will work if your file is .csv saved with "," seperate.

```
 $file = fopen($filename, "r");
    $headers = fgetcsv($file);
    while (($Data = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE){

    /*  echo "<pre>";
        print_r($Data);
        echo "</pre>";  */

    $sql = "INSERT into tbl_userdata ('name','svp_name','mobileno','email') values ('$Data[0]','$Data[1]','$Data[2]','$Data[3]')";
    echo $sql;

    }
```

Comment: give link to your demo excel file also if possible.

Comment: Just wait i am uploading it

Comment: @Root try this by saving your file in .csv format.i tried with .excel format for long but it did not workout but still if you are looking for .xls the look for PHPExcel reader script.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $Data is your total dataset, including the header if you have one.
So you have to loop through the $Data, using a foreach or a for loop for example:

```
$num = count($Data);
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
   echo $Data[$c] . "<br />";
}
```

You need to skip the first iteration if this is your header in the excel file.

After that, $Data[$c][0] is the name, $Data[$c][1] is the svp_name etc.
You query would look like this:

`$sql = "INSERT into tbl_userdata ('name','svp_name','mobileno','email') values ('$Data[$c][0]', '$Data[$c][1]', '$Data[$c][2]', '$Data[$c][3]')";`

Do not forget to actually execute your query, you are only defining the query itself and not executing it.

Combining everything will give you the following code in your while loop:

```
$num = count($Data);
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
   $sql = "INSERT into tbl_userdata ('name','svp_name','mobileno','email') values ('$Data[$c][0]', '$Data[$c][1]', '$Data[$c][2]', '$Data[$c][3]')";
   mysql_query($sql); //if you are using mysql
   $mysqli->query($sql); //if you are using mysqli, but then you should use a prepared statement
}
```

**EDIT :**
Looking at the excel file you provided you need a PHPExcel reader script, cause this is not a comma separated csv file. Try saving your excel file as a csv file with a comma seperator.

If you want to read an actual excel file try using:
https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Let  me try it

Comment: output of $num is 1 ,but echo `$Data[$c]` shows nothing

Comment: Where should i put the `forloop` is that in `while`?

Comment: I just saw your excel file. This is not a CSV with a "," separator. If you are uploading a excel file like this you will need a excel reader script.

Try:
https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: Or save it as a csv with a comma seperator

Answer (score 0):

Saved 'http://gksfapp.in/backend/19-Nov-2014%2002-31-34%20pm.xls' to test.csv.

```
$host = "localhost";

$user = "root";

$pass = "";

$db_name = "test";

$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);

$file = fopen('test.csv', "r");

while (($Data = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    $sql = "INSERT into tbl_userdata (name,svp_name,mobileno,email) values ('$Data[0]','$Data[1]','$Data[2]','$Data[3]')";
    mysql_query($sql);
}

fclose($file);
```

Change the above code with your database credentials and table name. Add proper exception handling too.